# Show File/Folder Hierachy as Grouped with Indentation

Tags: performance, vba

I was intrigued by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56395005/4717755) on SO and was able to come up with a reasonably efficient answer, but I'm interested in learning about further optimizations. You can certainly look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434762/4717755) to that original question for some explanations of how I've implemented certain logic, but I'm happy to answer questions as well.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowFilePaths()
    Dim rootFolder As String
    rootFolder = SelectFolder

    Dim pathArray As Variant
    pathArray = GetAllFiles(rootFolder)

    Dim folderGroups As Object
    Set folderGroups = BuildFolderDictionary(pathArray)

    '--- when debugging, this block just clears the worksheet to make it
    '    easier to rerun and test the code
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Sheet1.UsedRange.rows.Ungroup
    Loop While Err.Number = 0
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Clear
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '--- copy the array to the worksheet
    Const START_ROW As Long = 6
    Dim pathRange As Range
    Set pathRange = Sheet1.Range("A" & START_ROW).Resize(UBound(pathArray) + 1, 1)
    pathRange.Value = pathArray

    '------ now apply the indention levels to each line on the sheet
    '       and group the same rows
    Dim rowGroup As Variant
    Dim level As Long
    For Each rowGroup In folderGroups
        Dim theseRows As String
        theseRows = folderGroups(rowGroup)
        With pathRange.rows(theseRows)
            level = Len(rowGroup) - Len(Replace(rowGroup, "\", vbNullString)) - 1
            .IndentLevel = level
            If level < 8 Then
                .Group
            End If
        End With
    Next rowGroup
End Sub

Private Function SelectFolder() As String
    '--- returns the user-selected folder as a string
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, 17)
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        SelectFolder = objFolder.self.Path
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal rootPath As String, _
                             Optional ByVal onlyFolders As Boolean = False) As Variant
    '--- returns a sorted array of all filepaths in the given directory path
    Dim dirOptions As String
    If onlyFolders Then
        dirOptions = """ /a:d-h-s /b /s"
    Else
        dirOptions = """ /a:-h-s /b /s"
    End If
    Dim fOut() As String
    fOut = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & _
                                                    rootPath & _
                                                    dirOptions).StdOut.ReadAll, _
                 vbNewLine)
    QuickSort fOut, LBound(fOut), UBound(fOut)

    '--- the pathArray skips the first position from the fOut array
    '    because it's always blank
    Dim pathArray As Variant
    ReDim pathArray(1 To UBound(fOut), 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(fOut)
        pathArray(i, 1) = fOut(i)
    Next i
    GetAllFiles = pathArray
End Function

Private Function BuildFolderDictionary(ByRef paths As Variant) As Object
    Dim folders As Object
    Set folders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '--- scan all paths and create a dictionary of each folder and subfolder
    '    noting which items (rows) map into each dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(paths) To UBound(paths)
        Dim folder As String
        Dim pos1 As Long
        If Not IsEmpty(paths(i, 1)) Then
            pos1 = InStrRev(paths(i, 1), "\")   'find the last folder separator
            folder = Left$(paths(i, 1), pos1)
            If Not folders.Exists(folder) Then
                '--- new (sub)folder, create a new entry
                folders.Add folder, CStr(i) & ":" & CStr(i)
            Else
                '--- extisting (sub)folder, add to the row range
                Dim rows As String
                rows = folders(folder)
                rows = Left$(rows, InStr(1, rows, ":"))
                rows = rows & CStr(i)
                folders(folder) = rows
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set BuildFolderDictionary = folders
End Function

Private Sub QuickSort(ByRef Field() As String, ByVal LB As Long, ByVal UB As Long)
    '--- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/152333/4717755
    Dim P1 As Long, P2 As Long, Ref As String, TEMP As String

    P1 = LB
    P2 = UB
    Ref = Field((P1 + P2) / 2)

    Do
        Do While (Field(P1) < Ref)
            P1 = P1 + 1
        Loop

        Do While (Field(P2) > Ref)
            P2 = P2 - 1
        Loop

        If P1 <= P2 Then
            TEMP = Field(P1)
            Field(P1) = Field(P2)
            Field(P2) = TEMP

            P1 = P1 + 1
            P2 = P2 - 1
        End If
    Loop Until (P1 > P2)

    If LB < P2 Then Call QuickSort(Field, LB, P2)
    If P1 < UB Then Call QuickSort(Field, P1, UB)
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct about the Quicksort and that fixed my other issue.  Nice answer.